# Is there a Codename One benchmark app

Tags: codenameone

Here and there I read about dos and dont's performance wise.

But how can I get a feeling for what is feasible on the devices?

Is there sort of a Codename One benchmark app which can be used to measure things like rendering speed on device?

Answer (score 0):

We use the existing demo to test. Benchmarks aren't really important here as much as the "feel" of the app and overall smoothness which is what we use when testing a new port.

Benchamarking is hugely problematic due to the asynchronous nature of the underlying API's so one would be testing the wrong things if you are trying to measure graphics performance.

For profiling we use the native OS profiling tools especially on iOS where they are generally better.